# Can PHP attach to a running Windows process?

Tags: php, memory, process

Are there any PHP functions/libraries that I can use to attach to a running process under the Windows OS ?

I'm playing an abandonware game and I would like to make changes to data in various memory locations whilst the game is running.

The game doesn't use Shared Memory, IPC's.  I'm hoping PHP allows me to give the Process ID of the game, and then it can attach using some functions/library that I've not come across.

The GDB debgugger is one potential way forward, but I'd like to do everything in PHP if possible.

Any thoughts or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: This is far, far beyond the scope of PHP. There are much better suited languages to do this. I'm hesitant to make a recommendation because it's been so long since I've last dabbled in compiled languages, but I'm sure somebody will be able to come up with a suggestion. C will probably be the closest to PHP syntax-wise

Comment: So it's looking like I'm dusting off my C++ skills.  It's a shame really, I had hoped that streams or process control libraries might have had the answer.  I just didn't want to develop 2 programs that will interact with each in different languages.

Comment: Cool project. If you dust off your C++ skills, why not make a PHP module for doing this? Nothing should be out of the scope of a programming language, and PHP is maturing quite nicely now and this would make a great addition!

Comment: Far from what I've used so far in PHP, but it might be worthwhile to take a look at [Phalanger](http://www.php-compiler.net/).

Answer (score 0):

With PHP running on Windows you are able to create instances of ActiveX objects. But this will lead you to write an ActiveX class which gets all the information and does all the work. PHP would end for display only purposes and so you could create your html output directly with your ActiveX class / C++ / C# / whatever app.

Summary: For such a task PHP is not the best choice.